# Editable Dynamic ExposedDropDownMenuBox in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-exposeddropdown

I'm trying to get this drop down menu to be dynamic. When I type into the textfield, I expect the list to be updated (filtered for what the user types in) and the user can select from the filtered drop down list.

I've checked here, the sample code from the dev docs
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ExposedDropdownMenuBox(kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function1)

I found that material 3 drop down menu will block user input if it is in an expanded state. If a user starts to type and we say

```
onValueChange = { 
        selectedOptionText = it
        expanded = true
}
```

user is blocked from typing further because the ExposedDropdownMenu expanded blocks user input

How can I make a textfield dynamically open a drop down menu, and the list is updated based on user input? And the list items are selectable

To add some more context, I understand that DropdownMenu does not block user input if we say properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false)

```
DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false)
        )
```

But the UI behavior is not the same. I'm looking for DropdownMenuBox behavior with DropdownMenu properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is solved by taking the code from the docs

```
val options = listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5")
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
    expanded = expanded,
    onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
) {
    TextField(
        // The `menuAnchor` modifier must be passed to the text field for correctness.
        modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),
        value = selectedOptionText,
        onValueChange = { selectedOptionText = it },
        label = { Text("Label") },
        trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
        colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
    )
    // filter options based on text field value
    val filteringOptions = options.filter { it.contains(selectedOptionText, ignoreCase = true) }
    if (filteringOptions.isNotEmpty()) {
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
        ) {
            filteringOptions.forEach { selectionOption ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = { Text(selectionOption) },
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                        expanded = false
                    },
                    contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And we replace the nested ExposedDropdownMenu with

```
DropdownMenu(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.White)
        .exposedDropdownSize(true),
    properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
    expanded = expanded,
    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
)
```

the final code will look and behave as expected. When you type, the suggestions will follow dynamically and user input will not be blocked

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun docs() {
    val options = listOf("Option 1", "comment", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Egypt")
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
    ) {
        TextField(
            // The `menuAnchor` modifier must be passed to the text field for correctness.
            modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor(),
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = { selectedOptionText = it },
            label = { Text("Label") },
            trailingIcon = { ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded) },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(
                focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
                unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White
            ),
        )
        // filter options based on text field value
        val filteringOptions = options.filter { it.contains(selectedOptionText, ignoreCase = true) }
        if (filteringOptions.isNotEmpty()) {
            DropdownMenu(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.White)
                    .exposedDropdownSize(true)
                ,
                properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            ) {
                filteringOptions.forEach { selectionOption ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(selectionOption) },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                            expanded = false
                        },
                        contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when I change the text the dropdown automatically disappears and have to press on the text field again to see the results. Did u solve this issue as well?

Comment: @user924 Yes, this response exactly solves this issue, replacing the ExposedDropdownMenu with the DropdownMenu along with its modifiers.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. Good job!