# Jetpack Compose - ExposedDropdownMenu - Autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-exposeddropdown, exposeddropdownmenu

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete textfield (I sure hope Compose has a built-in one at some point, like XML did) using the `ExposedDropdownMenu` and while I've gotten it to basically work, it's acting very strange.

If I use this code below (ignore any bits that have things specific to my app, it should be pretty apparent) *then I cannot enter any text in the `TextField` using my physical keyboard, but using the software keyboard in the emulator allows me to type in it*:

```
val allLocations = listOf("FLSC") // just a hardcoded test list of a single value for now
val dropDownOptions = remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<String>()) }
val dropDownExpanded = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            modifier = modifier,
            expanded = dropDownExpanded.value,
            onExpandedChange = {
                dropDownExpanded.value = !dropDownExpanded.value
            }) {
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .menuAnchor()
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                        if (!focusState.isFocused)
                            dropDownExpanded.value = false
                    },
                value = viewModel.location.value.text, // stored in State in viewmodel
                label = {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.location),
                        style = TextStyle(
                            color = ShotTrackerColors.textFieldTextColor,
                            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1.fontSize
                        )
                    )
                },
                onValueChange = { enteredText ->
                    viewModel.onEvent(AddEditShotsEvent.EnteredLocation(enteredText))
                    
                    dropDownOptions.value =
                        allLocations.filter { it.contains(viewModel.location.value.text, ignoreCase = true) && it.lowercase() != viewModel.location.value.text.lowercase() }
                            .take(3)
                    
                    dropDownExpanded.value = dropDownOptions.value.isNotEmpty()
                }
            )
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = dropDownExpanded.value,
                onDismissRequest = {
                    dropDownExpanded.value = false
                },
            ) {
                dropDownOptions.value.forEach { text ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = {
                            Text(text = text)
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.onEvent(AddEditShotsEvent.EnteredLocation(text))
                        
                            dropDownExpanded.value = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

Like I said, it technically works, but only using the emulator software keyboard to type. My computer's physical keyboard does nothing, almost like the `TextField` is read-only.

*I've tried very similar code, from Stack Overflow here somewhere, and it acts about the same except that I can actually type with the physical keyboard, as long as I do not type any characters that would trigger the `ExposedDropdownMenu` to appear*. I can only type a single character if that character is contained in the dropdown options (so like an 'f' in this example). So it seems like the dropdown menu has something to do with blocking text entry but I just don't know how or why. Code for second one:

```
val allLocations = listOf("FLSC") // hardcoded test list
val dropDownExpanded = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
// no "dropDownOptions" here as that's basically below as the "filterOpts" var

ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = dropDownExpanded.value,
            onExpandedChange = {
                dropDownExpanded.value = !dropDownExpanded.value
            }
        ) {
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .menuAnchor()
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                value = viewModel.location.value.text,
                onValueChange = {
                    viewModel.onEvent(AddEditShotsEvent.EnteredLocation(it))
                },
                label = {
                    Text(stringResource(id = R.string.location))
                }
            )
            // filter options based on text field value (i.e. crude autocomplete)
            val filterOpts = if (viewModel.location.value.text.isNotBlank()) {
                allLocations.filter {
                    it.contains(viewModel.location.value.text, ignoreCase = true)
                }
            }
            else {
                emptyList()
            }

            if (filterOpts.isNotEmpty()) {
                ExposedDropdownMenu(
                    expanded = dropDownExpanded.value,
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        dropDownExpanded.value = false
                    }
                ) {
                    filterOpts.forEach { option ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            text = { Text(text = option) },
                            onClick = {
                                viewModel.onEvent(AddEditShotsEvent.EnteredLocation(option))

                                dropDownExpanded.value = false
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: did u solve this issue? I have the exact problem. For some reason text change updates are not triggered with physical keyboard. Also if I start typing with software keyboard then dropdown disappears for some reason but user has to be able to type something and see the dropdown always so he could choose something from the choices

Comment: some partial solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76039608/editable-dynamic-exposeddropdownmenubox-in-jetpack-compose but still dropdown hides automatically when I change the text